# Help with a "Template" folder

Tags: filesystems

i realize the title may be a bit hard to understand
so lets say i have a folder `/template` and in this case i have two "copies" of template (`/server1`,`/server2`) which are symlinks to /template. /template has no `/save` folder but I want it so `/server1/save` and `/server2/save` are unique and not linked between the two

Comment: This is totally confusing. First, you're giving absolute paths. Is this correct or are the paths actually relative to `$HOME`?  Second, what application is trying to access `/template`? Can it be configured to look at a per-server configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I don’t understand what you want. 
But, if I understand, then it’s impossible. 
(At least in any standard file system;
I don’t know enough about user-defined file systems.)

What you can do is make `server1` and `server2`
as actual, separate directories. 
Create a `save` subdirectory in each server directory. 
Link everything in the `template` directory
individually into each server directory:

```
$ ls -l template
total NNN
-rw-r--r-- 1 Walker Fowlkes  0 Mar 18 21:07 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 Walker Fowlkes  0 Mar 18 21:07 file2

$ ls -l s*
server1:
total NNN
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Walker Fowlkes 17 Mar 18 21:10 file1 -> ../template/file1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Walker Fowlkes 17 Mar 18 21:10 file2 -> ../template/file2
drwxr-xr-x 1 Walker Fowlkes  0 Mar 18 21:08 save

server2:
total NNN
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Walker Fowlkes 17 Mar 18 21:11 file1 -> ../template/file1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 Walker Fowlkes 17 Mar 18 21:11 file2 -> ../template/file2
drwxr-xr-x 1 Walker Fowlkes  0 Mar 18 21:09 save
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a template folder for new users (I think thats you are trying to refer to this) /etc/skel is the answer. Everything you put here is loaded every time a new user is created.